# What is the method for 'If loop does NOT break, run code'?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to write a for-loop to go through values, and if by the end of the loop it did not break, I want it to run some code. For example:

```py
for i in range(10):
    if someCondition:
        break
#If the loop did NOT break, then...
doSomething()
```

There is a roundabout method. For example,

```py
didNotBreak = True
for i in range(10)
    if someCondition:
        didNotbreak = False
        break
if didNotBreak:
    doSomething()
```

Is there a simpler method?

Comment: If you put an `else` clause on the loop, it will be run if the loop did not break.

Comment: Doesn't it do the opposite?

Answer (score 5):

You can use an `else` clause on the loop.

```
for i in range(10):
    if someCondition:
        break
else:
    #If the loop did NOT break, then...
    doSomething()
```

The `else` clause is executed if the loop completes without hitting a `break`.

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops which specifies:

> ... a loop’s else clause runs when no break occurs

Comment: Oh dear. It seems that I formatted that method wrong when I did it the first time, so I believed that it did the opposite of that. Thank you.