# Prints more than expected amount of times with for loop

Tags: python, printing

I have written a Python script that handles file extension names. This is the current code:

```
extensions = ['txt', 'jpg', 'gif', 'html']
fileName = input("Enter the name of the file: ")
newList = fileName.split(".")
print(newList)
for i in extensions:
    if newList[1] == i:
        print("Yes")
        break
    else:
        continue
    print("No")
```

If the print function is after the else clause, I get it printed 4 times because of the for loop. I then modified it and now as I've written it outside of if else loop, it isn't printed at all. How do I print it only once after checking all elements in the list and there are no extensions for the input?

Comment: Anyway, you seem to be looking for `print("yes" if fileName.split(".")[1] in ['txt', 'jpg', 'gif', 'html'] else "no")`

Comment: As you have written that code, `print("No")` is unreachable.  Hint: think about what `break` and `continue` actually do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66771270/what-is-the-method-for-if-loop-does-not-break-run-code

Comment: *"oh, I have tried for else but it didn't work"* - Hint: It is not what you use, but *how you use it* that matters.  `else:` can be used in many ways.  Some ways will do what you want.  Other ways won't.  Programming is like that.  You need to develop an understanding of the code that you write, and write it correctly to do what you want.  Programming is an art that requires precision.  Python does what you tell it to do, not what it thinks you mean.

Comment: Yes I've just started taking programming seriously and seems like stack overflow is a good way to keep going and do what I need to do, I'm just trying to gain programmer's logic, Idk if it's right to say that but yea, not so easy in the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this corrected code, the else block is associated with the for loop. It will be executed only if the loop completes without encountering a break statement, which means none of the extensions matched.

```
 extensions = ['txt', 'jpg', 'gif', 'html']
fileName = input("Enter the name of the file: ")
newList = fileName.split(".")
print(newList)

for i in extensions:
    if newList[1] == i:
        print("Yes")
        break
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: oh, I have tried for else but it didn't work, I guess I was writing something else too with print function. It works now, thank you so much <3

Answer (score 2):

This is good time to learn about sets. Convert the `extensions` from list to set and use `in` operator:

```py
extensions = {"txt", "jpg", "gif", "html"}
fileName = input("Enter the name of the file: ")

newList = fileName.split(".")

if newList[-1] in extensions:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `else` keyword on the `for` loop to achieve this. The `else` block of a `for` loop runs if all iteration of the loop have been executed WITHOUT `break`

```py
for i in extensions:
    if newList[1] == i:
        print("Yes")
        break
else:
    print("No")
```

The `else: continue` part in your code is redundant, as that is the default behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

The issue with your code is that you've included the print("no") inside the for loop and it becomes unreachable. Because regardless of whether `newList[1] == i`, it will always either break the loop or continue with the next iteration. The answer by hezare digital suggests using the else clause on the for loop. That works too, but here's another solution. It uses a flag, which can be quite useful.

```
extensions = ['txt', 'jpg', 'gif', 'html']
fileName = input("Enter the name of the file: ")
newList = fileName.split(".")
extension_found = False

for ext in extensions:
    if len(newList) > 1 and newList[1] == ext:
        print("Yes")
        extension_found = True
        break

if not extension_found:
    print("No")
```

Comment: in the time that i finished my response, so many other people provided an answer. i'm shocked, so i've just decided to let everyone know that i did not know when i posted it